# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in MVC 5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Full of Error in console:     Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:22339' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Enable cors extensions on your chrome browser and check. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en.

Answer (score 0):

In startup.auth.cs add the following code at the start of the ConfigureAuth method. You will need to install this Microsoft.Owin.Cors nuget package.

`app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`